# How to reverse a Force?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(Hello, sorry if this is a really stupid question. I'm not good at coding and I probably don't understand what I'm doing)

I'm doing boids on Unity 3D and I'm trying to block them in a square area. Therefore I added  Forces, one if they were going to far on the x and another one on the z axis.
**However I don't understand how to make a force so that they don't go too far on the -x and -z axis. How do I reverse the forces so those boids stay inside my area ?**

Here's my x and z boundaries :

```
        //Force x
        float distX = Mathf.Max(0, transform.position.x);
        if (distX > 20)
        {
            float forceReject = Mathf.Clamp(5, 1.0f - (distX / 2), 2) * forceRejectGround;
            sumForces += new Vector3(-forceReject, 0, 0);
        }
        
        //Force z
        float distZ = Mathf.Max(0, transform.position.z);
        if (distZ > 20)
        {
            float forceReject = Mathf.Clamp(5, 1.0f - (distZ / 2), 2) * -forceRejectGround;
            sumForces += new Vector3(0, 0, forceReject);
        }
```

Here's the whole code because some asked it (however it's in french sorry)

```
public class Boid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float zoneRepulsion = 2;
    public float zoneAlignement = 9;
    public float zoneAttraction = 30;
    public float hauteurSol = 0;

    public float forceRepulsion = 15;
    public float forceAlignement = 3;
    public float forceAttraction = 20;
    public float forceRejetSol = 100;

    public Vector3 target = new Vector3();
    public float forceTarget = 15;
    public bool goToTarget = false;
    public bool stopToTarget = false;
    private bool atTarget = false;

    public Vector3 velocity = new Vector3();
    public float maxSpeed = 10;
    public float minSpeed = 5;

    public bool drawGizmos = true;
    public bool drawLines = true;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 sumForces = new Vector3();
        Color colorDebugForce = Color.black;
        float nbForcesApplied = 0;

        foreach (Boid otherBoid in BoidManager.sharedInstance.roBoids)
        {
            Vector3 vecToOtherBoid = otherBoid.transform.position - transform.position;
            Vector3 forceToApply = new Vector3();

            //Si on doit prendre en compte cet autre boid (plus grande zone de perception)
            if (vecToOtherBoid.sqrMagnitude < zoneAttraction * zoneAttraction)
            {
                //Si on est entre attraction et alignement
                if (vecToOtherBoid.sqrMagnitude > zoneAlignement * zoneAlignement)
                {
                    //On est dans la zone d'attraction uniquement
                    forceToApply = vecToOtherBoid.normalized * forceAttraction;
                    float distToOtherBoid = vecToOtherBoid.magnitude;
                    float normalizedDistanceToNextZone = ((distToOtherBoid - zoneAlignement) / (zoneAttraction - zoneAlignement));
                    float boostForce = (4 * normalizedDistanceToNextZone);
                    if (!goToTarget) //Encore plus de cohésion si pas de target
                        boostForce *= boostForce;
                    forceToApply = vecToOtherBoid.normalized * forceAttraction * boostForce;
                    colorDebugForce += Color.green;
                }
                else
                {
                    //On est dans alignement, mais est on hors de répulsion ?
                    if (vecToOtherBoid.sqrMagnitude > zoneRepulsion * zoneRepulsion)
                    {
                        //On est dans la zone d'alignement uniquement
                        forceToApply = otherBoid.velocity.normalized * forceAlignement;
                        colorDebugForce += Color.blue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //On est dans la zone de repulsion
                        float distToOtherBoid = vecToOtherBoid.magnitude;
                        float normalizedDistanceToPreviousZone = 1 - (distToOtherBoid / zoneRepulsion);
                        float boostForce = (4 * normalizedDistanceToPreviousZone);
                        forceToApply = vecToOtherBoid.normalized * -1 * (forceRepulsion * boostForce);
                        colorDebugForce += Color.red;

                    }
                }


                sumForces += forceToApply;
                nbForcesApplied++;
                
            }
        }

        //On fait la moyenne des forces, ce qui nous rend indépendant du nombre de boids
        sumForces /= nbForcesApplied;

        //On ajoute le rejet du sol
        float distSol = Mathf.Max(0,transform.position.y - hauteurSol);
        if (distSol < 2)
        {
            float forceRejet = Mathf.Pow(1.0f - (distSol / 2), 2) * forceRejetSol;
            sumForces += new Vector3(0, forceRejet, 0);
        }

        //Rejet du plafond
        float distPlaf = Mathf.Max(5, transform.position.y);
        if (distPlaf > 10)
        {
            float forceRejet = Mathf.Clamp(5, 1.0f - (distPlaf / 2), 2) * -forceRejetSol;
            sumForces += new Vector3(0, forceRejet, 0);
        }

        //Rejet pour la limite d' x
        float distX = Mathf.Max(0, transform.position.x);
        if (distX > 20)
        {
            float forceRejet = Mathf.Clamp(5, 1.0f - (distX / 2), 2) * forceRejetSol;
            sumForces += new Vector3(-forceRejet, 0, 0);
        }
        //Rejet pour la limite de -x
        if (distX < -15)
        {
            float forceRejetXNeg = Mathf.Clamp(5, 1.0f - (distX / 2), 2) * forceRejetSol;
            sumForces += new Vector3(forceRejetXNeg, 0, 0);
        }
        //Rejet pour la limite d' z
        float distZ = Mathf.Max(0, transform.position.z);
        if (distZ > 20)
        {
            float forceRejet = Mathf.Clamp(5, 1.0f - (distZ / 2), 2) * -forceRejetSol;
            sumForces += new Vector3(0, 0, forceRejet);
        }
        //Rejet pour la limite de -z
        if (distZ < -15)
        {
            float forceRejetZNeg = Mathf.Clamp(5, 1.0f - (distZ / 2), 2) * -forceRejetSol;
            sumForces += new Vector3(0, 0, forceRejetZNeg);
        }

        //Si on a une target, on l'ajoute
        float distToTarget = 0;
        if (goToTarget)
        {
            Vector3 vecToTarget = target - transform.position;
            distToTarget = vecToTarget.magnitude;
            if (distToTarget < 0.5f)
            {
                goToTarget = false;
                atTarget = true;
            }
            else
            {
                atTarget = false;
                Vector3 forceToTarget = vecToTarget.normalized * forceTarget;
                if (distToTarget < 5 && stopToTarget)
                    forceToTarget *= 10;
                sumForces += forceToTarget;
                colorDebugForce += Color.magenta;
                nbForcesApplied++;
                if (drawLines)
                    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, target, Color.magenta);
            }
        }

        //Debug
        if (drawLines)
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + sumForces, colorDebugForce / nbForcesApplied);

        //On freine
        velocity += -velocity * 10 * Vector3.Angle(sumForces, velocity) / 180.0f * Time.deltaTime;

        //on applique les forces
        velocity += sumForces * Time.deltaTime;

        //On limite la vitesse
        if (velocity.sqrMagnitude > maxSpeed * maxSpeed)
            velocity = velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
        if (velocity.sqrMagnitude < minSpeed * minSpeed)
            velocity = velocity.normalized * minSpeed;

        //Si on doit freiner sur la cible, on limite la vitesse
        if ((goToTarget || atTarget) && stopToTarget)
            if (distToTarget < 3)
                velocity = velocity.normalized * distToTarget/10.0f;


        //On regarde dans la bonne direction        
        if (velocity.sqrMagnitude > 0)
            transform.LookAt(transform.position + velocity);

        //Debug
        if (drawLines)
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + velocity, Color.blue);

        //Deplacement du boid
        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (drawGizmos)
        {
            // Répulsion
            Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 1.0f);
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, zoneRepulsion);
            // Alignement
            Gizmos.color = new Color(0, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, zoneAlignement);
            // Attraction
            Gizmos.color = new Color(0, 0, 1, 1.0f);
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, zoneAttraction);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: by stays inside the area you mean they should immediately stop like hitting a wall or rather slow down and by dragged back to the center smoothly like lets say in a gravitational cloud?

Comment: @derHugo yeah slow down and by dragged back to the center smoothly like in a gravitational cloud is more the idea.

Comment: The limits are walls and when you hit a wall you will bounce off with a force in opposite direction.

Comment: @jdweng is this a question or an answer ? Either way I  currently don't use any walls because I rather try to use forces. (in fact I don't understand why but my boids can go throughout walls even if both have a rigidbody)

Comment: Could you post a full code example? How exactly are you using `sumForces` in the end?

Comment: @derHugo I added the whole code if it can help but I'm really sorry if it's messy.

Comment: If you do not use walls than how can you stop object from leaving screen? Newton says that a body in motion will stay in motion until an outside force acts upon it.  The wall is an outside force.

Comment: so for starters: If you want to use physics then rather use a [`Rigidbody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) and move your things into `FixedUpdate` .. then don't read or apply anything via `transform` (otherwise you break any physics and collision based movement) but rather go through the `Rigidbody` e.g. using `AddForce` which already calculates the resulting velocity for you and reacts to collisions etc

Comment: @jdweng ... well .. that is what OP is asking about ^^

Comment: @jdweng The First code that I showed after "Here's my X and Y boundaries" is a force that I use to prevent my boids to go too far. And it works. I just don't know how to use it in the other direction

Comment: You could/should further even consider rather using a proper [Particle System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ChoosingYourParticleSystem.html) which provides things like [Force fields](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParticleSystemForceField.html) etc so you can simply enclose your boids by 6 force fields which smoothly reflect (accelerate) them back towards the center of the cube area

Comment: @derHugo I will try your suggestions thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you say this worked for you and you just ask about the "negative" direction you can simply invert check.

However, this

```
var forceReject = Mathf.Clamp(5, 1.0f - distX / 2, 2) * forceRejectGround;
```

seems to make little sense to me. You already know that `distX > 20` so that you basically do

```
var forceReject = Mathf.Clamp(5, -9f /*or less*/, 2) * forceRejectGround;
```

which of course will always return `2 * forceRejectGround` anyway. So this is either wrong or just completely redundant ;)

Also

```
distX < -15
```

can never be true since you already did

```
distX = Mathf.Max(0, transform.x);
```

so it can only be `0` or positive!

---

So basically you could probably simply do something like e.g.

```
//Force x
var x = transform.position.x;
if (Mathf.Abs(x) > 20) 
// basically equals
//if(x > 20 || x < -20)
{
    // will be positive if x > 20 and negative if x < -20 
    // (assuming forceRejectGround is positive of course)
    var forceReject = forceRejectGround * Mathf.Sign(x);

    sumForces -= Vector3.right * forceReject;
}
        
//Force z
var z = transform.position.z;
if (Mathf.Abs(z) > 20)
{
    var forceReject = forceRejectGround * Mathf.Sign(z);

    sumForces -= Vector3.up * forceReject;
}
```

---

However, as mentioned in the comments, in general you rather want to use a proper [`Rigidbody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) not do anything via `transform` at all but rather only through e.g. [`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) which already calculates the resulting velocities for you and reacts with collisions etc.

Or even further directly go with a [Particle System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ChoosingYourParticleSystem.html) and e.g. have your boid particles enclosed in [Force fields](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParticleSystemForceField.html)

Comment: It's very clear and well explained, thank you !